# nodejs command not found on VPS

Tags: node.js, vps

While setting up a Centos7 VPS server via SSH I have the problem that NodeJS command isn't found.

Installing the latest stable version of nodejs using:
`curl —silent —location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -`

...results in the instruction: `Run 'sudo yum install -y nodejs' to install Node.js 10.x and npm`

...running the above command it says: `nodejs-10.16.3-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

But if I then check the installed versions it isn't found:

```
[root@server ~]# node -v
v10.16.3
[root@server ~]# npm -v
6.9.0
[root@server ~]# nodejs -v
-bash: nodejs: command not found
```

I've seen several sources usins `nodejs -v` to check the version but I'm half convinced they're wrong. Although followup tests like `nano` also fail.

I've tried re-installing several different ways but it results in the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add an alias to node can solve your problem.